# Persistent volume claim - mount path

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, azure-files

I have a `pv` like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata: 
  name: azurefile

spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: cloudshare
    readOnly: false
```

and a `pvc` like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:  
  name: azurefile
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: azurefile
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

on deployments i have the following

```
      volumes:      
        - name: my-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: azurefile
      volumeMounts:
          - name:  my-storage
            mountPath:  "/home/myapp/newapp/"
```

My understanding is that under the path `/home/myapp/newapp/` in the containers ,the `azure` fileshare `cloudshare`'s content will be accessible. So, whatever i have in `cloudshare` will be visible here. Does `pvc` or `pv` creates folders under the `cloudshare`? , the reason i ask is ,
I have a `WORKDIR` in my `dockerimage` which is actually in the same `mountpath` like below

`WORKDIR /home/myapp/newapp/reta-app/` .

For some reason `reta-app` folder is getting created inside the `cloudshare`. Is this a normal behaviour or i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Does `pvc` or `pv` create folders under the `cloudshare`?

No.  A Kubernetes PersistentVolume is just some storage somewhere, and a PersistentVolumeClaim is a way of referencing a PV (that may not immediately exist).  Kubernetes does absolutely no management of any of the content in a persistent volume; it will not create directories on startup, copy content from the image into a volume, or anything else.

Comment: `WORKDIR` in `dockerimage` creates folder inside the `cloudshare`

Comment: That will create a directory inside the Docker image.  At `docker build` time it has no idea that anything will be mounted anywhere; the resulting image may or may not run in Kubernetes, may or may not run with a volume mounted, it may or may not be the shared storage you're describing here, and so on.